# sort item Of the method asc & desc

Tags: jquery, ecmascript-6

I have a button that has two modes. The first sort order is descending. Second sort order ascending. I want our boxes to be sorted in this way.

We put our data in customSort. And here we have defined a variable called timeToNum. Its task is to get the clock and convert it to a timestamp. After this step (time + timestamp). Clock boxes for sorting (time). The change of timeToNum has not yet been made. Only we have set a name for it. You must create this variable. If you do not know this method. You can sort these boxes by yourself.

```js
let FlyList = [{
    "time": "15:20",
  },
  {
    "time": "15:10",
  },
  {
    "time": "18:40",
  },
  {
    "time": "23:40",
  }
];

// Sort Array
function customSort(array, field, Desc, type) {

  if (!type && field.toLowerCase().indexOf('time') !== -1) type = 'time';

  switch (type) {
    case 'time':
      Desc ? list.sort((a, b) => this.timeToNum(a[field]) - this.timeToNum(b[field])) : list.sort((a, b) => this.timeToNum(b[field]) - this.timeToNum(a[field]));
      break;
    default:
      var type = Desc ? true : false;
      array.sort(function(a, b) {
        if (type) return a[field] - b[field];
        else return b[field] - a[field];
      });
      break;
  }
};
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  background: skyblue;
}

.full-item {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  background: grey;
}

.full-item .button-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: #B33771;
}

.full-item .button-item button {
  /*margin: 30px 45%;*/
}

.full-item .item-sort {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.full-item .item-sort:first-child {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.full-item .item-sort .item {
  width: 90%;
  height: 80px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.item-sort .item .pic {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3B3B98;
  float: left;
}

.item-sort .item .time {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #1B9CFC;
  float: right;
}

.item-sort .item .time span {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-item">
  <div class="button-item">
    <p>Sort By </p>
    <button id="sort-asc-desc">Asc/Desc</button>
  </div>
  <div class="item-sort">

    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic" style="background: green">image</div>
      <div class="time" style="background: green"><span>{{time}}</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic" style="background: red">image</div>
      <div class="time" style="background: red"><span>{{time}}</span></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic" style="background: grey">image</div>
      <div class="time" style="background: grey"><span>{{time}}</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="pic" style="background: teal">image</div>
      <div class="time" style="background: teal"><span>{{time}}</span></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

I have used the javascript method 6.
You can use jQuery or Javascript 6. To sort the boxes.

Comment: What is `this` in the `customSort()` function?

Comment: Where do you call `customSort()`?

Comment: Buttons don't have a mode. Maybe you should use a checkbox or radio buttons to choose the direction.

Comment: We put our data in customSort. And here we have defined a variable called timeToNum. Its task is to get the clock and convert it to a timestamp. After this step (time + timestamp). Clock boxes for sorting (time). The change of timeToNum has not yet been made. Only we have set a name for it. You must create this variable. If you do not know this method. You can sort these boxes by yourself.

Comment: You can ignore customSort. And your method of use.

Comment: I'm voting to close this post as off-topic because it just states a school exercise, without any attempt to solve it or asking a question about it.